# Would any platforms have problems with missing PHP closing tags?

Tags: php, syntax

I've come across some open source PHP files that start with the expected `<?php` but do not contain a `?>` to end it.

As far as I can tell, they work fine on Apache with PHP 8.0

Which platforms (if any) would have a problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don’t worry.

#### This is fine.

It’s an acceptable way to format a PHP file *only* if the file is purely PHP code and not something like HTML sprinkled with PHP snippets. It is actually preferred to *not* have a PHP closing tag.

As explained in [the official PHP manual section on tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo "Hello world";
>
> // ... more code
>
> echo "Last statement";
>
> // the script ends here with no PHP closing tag
> ```

I have actually had to deal with some WordPress installs that failed because `wp-config.php`, which should have no PHP closing tag `?>`, somehow had a closing tag added *and* had empty whitespace at the end of the file that choked WordPress on a PHP/FastCGI setup.